# PHPStorm SFTP connection using two factor authenticaton (TOTP)

Tags: sftp, phpstorm, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to connect with the server in PHPStorm but I'm having trouble because the server uses a two factor authentication (TOTP).

I was googling for it, but didn't found anything.

Here is my PHPStorm configuration for deployment

[image: PHPStorm configuration]

When I try to connect with this configuration I receive the error:

> SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures for serv1

The same error raises even when I click in "Test SFTP connection". As I posted in the comments, the auth types are: "Password" and "Key pair (OpenSSH or PuTTY)".

My configuration:

> - Ubuntu 14.04;
> - PHPStorm 10.0.2;
> - The server runs a CentOS;

Comment: Remove the "Save password" and you will be prompted for the password, I guess. You can't store the the second factor in the applicateion. It does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it not worked. Even the "Test SFTP connection" raises the same error. I don't want to store the second factor, I just put the image because I don't see any option to configure the authentication to use two factors.

Comment: what are the auth types? It really depends on how the second factor is implemented on server. I am no fan of such IDEs with integrated everything. I would rather set up `sshfs` mount to do the same with less pain.

Comment: The auth types are: "Password" and "Key pair (OpenSSH or PuTTY)". I didn't know the `sshfs` but I'll give it a try.